# How can i write a function to generate random sample from the given density function above using Inverse Transformation method?

Tags: r

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHkYK.png
f(x) = 1/2*e^-|x-2|,  −∞ < x < ∞

Write a function to generate random sample from the density function above using Inverse
Transformation method by taking sample size n = 10^4. Please take θ parameter as 2. After generating random sample do not forget to plot the sample and check sample statistics.

```
theta <- 2
n <- 10^4
set.seed(361)
u <- runif(n)
x <- theta + log(2*u)

hist(x, prob = TRUE, main ="Pareto(9,2)")
y <- seq(1, 40, 0.01)
lines(y, (1/2)*(exp(1)^(theta-y)),col="red")
```

Comment: You should show what you have attempted as far as searching and making an initial stab at building an answer to your obvious HW. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822  and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete . You might start by showing us how to invert that function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.